# Need help understanding Angular $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angularjs-scope

I'm utilizing DatePicker, a Bootstrap component written in Angular, to display colored dots on a calendar date when users have Meetup events scheduled.  The Meetup API functionality is working perfectly, but when I try to populate the DatePicker, I get an "uncaught reference error" for the javascript function.  I think the $scope variable is tripping me up.  I've tried writing markMeetingOnDate() several different ways, but I've never worked with AngularJS before and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // This function results in an uncaught reference error
    function markMeetingOnDate(dateString) {
      dateInput = Date.parse(dateString)
      $scope.events = [{
        date: dateInput,
        status: 'full'    // colors the calendar date
      }];
    };

    // This code that does the same thing as above function works
    testDateString = "Thursday, September 17, 2015";
    dateInput = Date.parse(testDateString);
    $scope.events = [{
      date: dateInput,
      status: 'full'
    }];

});
```

.php

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <h4>Meetup Calendar</h4>
        <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;" id="DatepickerOnLeft">
          <?php
            // get all events for this member - $response is a JSON array
            $response = $meetup->getEvents(array(
              'member_id' => '190559018',
              'time' => '0,2m',
              'only' => 'group.name,venue.name,venue.address_1,venue.address_2,venue.zip,venue.city,venue.state,venue.name,time,event_url,name'
            ));

            // mark all events on the calendar
            $numOfMeetings = count($response);
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfMeetings; $i++) {
              $date = date('l, F d, Y', $response[$i]->time / 1000);
              echo "Date is: $date";
              echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                 , 'markMeetingOnDate(' . json_encode($date) . ');'
                 , '</script>'
              ;
            }
          ?>
          <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="false" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
        </div>


        <div id="MeetupDetailsOnRight">
          <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can't access `markMeetingOnDate()` from script tag , context in script tag is not angular scope it is in `window` namespace. Do yourself a favor and only use php as api data source for angular

Comment: @charlietfl are you saying there's no way to update the DatePicker once it's created?  And am I not using PHP as an API data source for Angular?  I'm acting on a Meetup object created in PHP.

Comment: sure you can if you do it in angular context. Would be so much simpler not trying to render all this with php and just make an api call for data and let angular manage the view rendering

Comment: as far as api data source goes...have angular make ajax calls for json using `$http` and let the view be managed by angular based on scope data

Comment: Can you point me to some resources that might help me better understand how to do this?  This is my first time playing with AngularJS

Comment: just about any angular tutorial. The one in docs site is well structured

Comment: You could pass all this data shown to javascript variables using php and pull the data into angular from global variable namespace also. Most use ajax though and separate html from data